# Blender Molecular Script not working

Tags: add-on, physics

I have recently been working with Manaflow's liquid physics and saw a youtube video on the molecular script. I downloaded the 2.8 version of the script, and installed it into blender, but in the '*n*' panel, I cannot see the options like it shows in the tutorials. I am using the portable version of blender 2.8. I tried it on portable Blender 3.0, and even downloaded the 2.7 script and tried it on blender 2.7. It is not working. Is it because I am using the portable version?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please add a pointer to where you downloaded the script from and perhaps the youtube video?  Also, it would help to know how you installed the script and get a screenshot of the info window showing any messages from around that time.

Comment: No Problem! I downloaded it from this github page: https://github.com/scorpion81/Blender-Molecular-Script/releases

Comment: I unfortunately don't have a screenshot at this moment, sorry

Comment: I tried to install the script 2 different ways. I tried installing the zip file from the preferences menu under addons.

Comment: I also unzipped the file in the scripts folder in file manager for blender

Comment: I installed it in 2.93.6 from the zip file.  It took a minute, but eventually it showed up in the add-ons list and I enabled it.  Then I added a particle system to a plane and went to the Particles Properties tab in the Properties editor.  The _Molecule_ panel is present and so I tried to bake a simulation.  That "did something" but I don't know what to expect.  If you couldn't get that far, I'm guess it is because you're using the portable version, but that should show up as errors in the info window.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try that out.